# Find max length from a collection of strings

Tags: python

I was working on solving another problem here, but ran into a step where I'm uncertain on how to calculate a length.

Sample data:

```
file_content = [
    '"Track","Artist","Album","Time"',
    '"Computer Love","Kraftwerk","Computer World","7:15"',
    '"Paranoid Android","Radiohead","OK Computer","6:27"'
]
```

Goal:
Calculate whichever row has the longest length of characters and return that value.  Basically, find the sum of characters of the `dict.values()` and the max value of *that* from the collection.

I've tried to use nested comprehensions, but I'm getting stuck somewhere.  Here's what I've tried so far:

```
import csv
rows = [r for r in csv.DictReader(file_content)]
max([sum(len(v)) for row in rows for v in row.values()])
```

Comment: @user3483203 That would include the quote and comma characters.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your question that they *shouldn't* be included.  Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't stated well enough but if you looked at what I've tried, you can see what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hypothetically, what value _should_ be returned here?

Comment: `max([len(''.join(row.values())) for row in rows])`

Comment: @Kevin `row.values()` <- the sum of the characters, and then the maximum of that collection.

Comment: @user3483203 That is perfect.  Feel free to post an answer with a short explanation and I'll accept it.

Comment: Allow me to rephrase. What number (or string?) should be returned from this function, given this input? I'm looking for something like `"Paranoid Android"` or `16` or `[16, 9, 11, 4]` or whatever it is you expect to see as the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a list of dictionaries, and you want to find the total length of each list item's values, and identify the maximum length:

Here is a solution using a list comprehension and `str.join`:

```
lengths = [
    len(''.join(row.values())) for row in rows
]

max(lengths)
```

```
40
```

---

Your current attempt is actually quite close, you just divide your expressions incorrectly.  Here is a working version:

```
[
    sum(len(i) for i in row.values())
    for row in rows
]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Using Pandas

Since the csv contains a tabular structure, we can use pandas as well.

```
import pandas as pd
```

---

File can be loaded using `df = pd.read_csv(path)`, which returns the following DataFrame:

```
Track                      Artist     Album           Time
Computer  Love             Kraftwerk  Computer World  7:15
Paranoid  Android          Radiohead     OK Computer  6:27
```

Then we can concatenate the rows and take the max value of the length of the combined strings

```
df["Concat"] = [''.join(row.astype(str)) for row in df.values]

Track           Artist      Album           Time    Concat
Computer Love   Kraftwerk   Computer World  7:15    Computer LoveKraftwerkComputer World7:15
Paranoid Android    Radiohead   OK Computer 6:27    Paranoid AndroidRadioheadOK Computer6:27

df["Concat"].str.len().max()
#40
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work:

```
max([len(i) for i in file_content])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the row, you can pass a custom key to max:

```
import csv

file_content = [
    '"Track","Artist","Album","Time"',
    '"Computer Love","Kraftwerk","Computer World","7:15"',
    '"Paranoid Android","Radiohead","OK Computer","6:27"'
]
rows = [r for r in csv.DictReader(file_content)]
result = max(rows, key=lambda r: sum(map(len, r.values())))
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'Track': 'Computer Love', 'Album': 'Computer World', 'Time': '7:15', 'Artist': 'Kraftwerk'}
```

Comment: I was looking for a literal numerical length, but this is a useful method to know; thanks!